# Special characters (Swedish) don't work in Chromium

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, language-support

In Swedish there are three extra letters (åäö) in the alphabet that function perfectly in every other application in Xubuntu 12.04 except for Chromium (I can type them in the Terminal but they show up as `???`). I can't type them anywhere in Chromium, including any forms on any pages.

I've tried installing Chrome but can't because of dependencies.

I've tried installing older version of Chromium but I don't know how/where.

I've installed Ibus but any time I select Swedish there it jumps back to "Input method off" and seems like generally shitty software.

Is there any solution to this or is this just one of the other million or so bugs and glitches that I have to live with in Ubuntu?

Edit: My locale:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Go to chrome://settings and set the encoding to UFT-8 (Unicode)

Comment: @the_Seppi Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like your locale is broken. Can you please run the `locale` command in a terminal window. Then edit your question and add to it the command output.

*Edit:*

Ok, seeing that your locale is not set at all, hence defaulting to POSIX, I suggest that you run this command:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

which sets the LANG environment variable in `/etc/default/locale`.

Then re-login and start Chromium to check if it makes a difference.

Comment: All right. Done. Don't forget that they (the characters) work in every other application though.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson: Ok, I just edited my answer.